# Random number generation and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random

I've been creating a random element generator of my first text adventure game, to be more specific, this:

```
    Random Generation = new Random();
    List<Integer> interact = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int generator = Generation.nextInt(5) + 3; generator > 0; generator--) {
        interact.add(Generation.nextInt(10));
    };
    System.out.println(interact);
```

Here, generator defines the amount of elements, and interact its a list that contains random numbers which represent different interactive objects, the thing is, i need elements don't repeat.

I was thinking in a `int a = Generation.nextInt(3); if (a != interact[]) {interact.add(a)} else {generator++};` but I don't know how to set an `[any]` in comparing arrays.

Comment: "*i've seen some previous questions, but i don't think they apply to my case*" => so you've seen the suggestion to put the numbers in an array and shuffle? Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Actually i didn't understand you perfectly ,do you want to generate random unique key ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I think yeah, i need the generator not repeat elements, but always maintaining that numbers of elements of generator var, i edited the question, i maked an error in interact range, i made it more big.

Comment: What you want to achieve is unclear

Comment: @assylias actually i dont think that one appeared when i searched, but just to make clear, i need that generator creates the exact amount of elements than generator, so maybe it can avoid be repeateable, but if it's something like a set, the `generator--` will still activate, and game will have 1 less element than what it should.

Comment: @RC i need that generator creates the exact amount of elements than generator, AND avoid be repeatable, so if it's something like a set, the generator-- will still activate, and game will have 1 less element than what it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC your requirements are:

- Game must have an "element list" of size `3 <= numberOfItems <= 8`. Where `numberOfItems` must be randomized each time.
- The "element list" must contain exactly `numberOfItems` random integers between 0 and 10.

How about this?

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    Set<Integer> interact = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int numberOfItems = generator.nextInt(5) + 3;
    while (interact.size() < numberOfItems) {
        interact.add(generator.nextInt(10));
    }
```

It will keep adding distinct elements to `interact` until it reaches the designated capacity `numberOfItems`.

Comment: you should remove the trailing ; in the while loop

Answer (score -1):

Modify your for loop this way:

```
for (int generator = Generation.nextInt(5) + 3; generator > 0; generator--) {
        int randomedNumber = 0;
        do {
          randomedNumber = Generation.nextInt(10);
        } while(interact.contains(randomedNumber))
        interact.add(randomedNumber);
};
```

You random a number, if it's in a list - you random again, if it's not - you add it to the list and move on to the next, pretty straightforward.